# Lumen 5.2 authentication

Tags: php, api, authentication, lumen

Trying to do a very simple api authentication using lumen 5.2

That is just check the header `HTTP_key` value to the hardcoded key value in lumen. If correct then process the api else throw an error.

I was able to implement it in php using the below code. I simply am not able to do the same in lumen. I previously used codeigniter only. So kind of new to the framework

```
public function auth()  {
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_KEY'])) {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_KEY'] = 0;
    }
    if (!($_SERVER['HTTP_KEY'] === $this->key)) {
        $error = array('status' => 'Error', 'msg' => 'Authentication Failed');
        $this->response($this->json($error), 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a lool at https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: What's not working with that code?

Comment: The thing is that i need to use the auth function on all http calls. What should i do ?